# TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties. AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, compiler-errors

This is my code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
function getCombos(masterword){
    var combos:Array;
    var a:Array;
    var i:int;
    var l:int;
    function nextLetter(a,l,key,used){
        var i:int;
        if(key.length == l){
            return;
        }
     for(i=0;i<l;i++){
            if(used.indexOf(""+i)<0){
                combos[key + a[i]]="";
                nextLetter(a,l,key + a[i],used + i);
            }
        }
    }
    a = masterword.split("");
    l = a.length;
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        combos[a[i]] = "";
        nextLetter(a, l, a[i], "" + i);
        trace("good")
    }
    return combos;
}


btnSolve.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, solve)
function solve(Event:MouseEvent){
    var wordString = wordTxt.text
    getCombos(wordString);

}
```

I have no idea what is wrong with this...
Any help here? I'm not that great with AS3 and the syntax.
BTW I am trying to make a Scrabble Solver.

Comment: What line is throwing the error?   Where does `btnSolve` get defined/initialized?

Comment: The error is occuring at getCombos() and solve();

Comment: I suspect 'combos[a[i]] = ""' is causing the error, but I don't know what is wrong with it.

Comment: Permit debugging and check the line with the error!

Comment: I did. It said that the error was on the line after the last for loop which is ' combos[a[i]] = "" '

Comment: I don't know why that is causing the error though.